# Different output when run on Azure than on local build

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, encoding

I have a C#, .NET MVC 4.5 web app with an action method which calls out to a web service with a query string parameter.  Something like "/home/getvalue?q=test@test.net"

I'm using Encoding.UTF8 and my return code looks like this:

```
return Content(responseText);
```

This outputs as: **6^.a308666-86** which is correct.

However, when I publish this code to Azure, the same code outputs as: **6$.e3$8.60688~**  I've ensured that the service is returning the correct output but when it's run through return Content(responseText) the output gets wonky as you see above.

I'm not entirely sure if Azure is encoding the result as something else?

Comment: try using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505216(v=vs.118).aspx overload

Comment: So something like:  return Content(responseText, "text/plain", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8); ?

Comment: I used the above overload and still seeing the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is a difference in the local and remote configuration. I would check the environment variables for your web app, and compare them with your local app to see if there's any differences (i.e. CLR version, IIS version). You can check environment variables with the SCM site, which is available at:

https://your-site-name-here.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env

Comment: Turns out it was a configuration issue.  My web.config Release file had an erroneous semi-colon in the web service URL.